# Using python threads to access a lot of data

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a lot of panda data frames. I am getting information from them and then returning some information. Because the function I am using takes a lot of time, around 5s per loop and i am making a lot of loops, I want to paralellize it.

First I tried process from multiprocessing module. The problem was that I have a lot of read-only data stored in memory, and different processes was not a good idea, as the use different memory.

So I decided to give a try at threads. I want to call a function many times, with the input split into parts. So instead of accessing around 10k data frames in one time, I am trying to access around 1k data frames per function call, but running 12 threads.

My idea was:

```
def pare():        
relist = list(reduced_stocks.keys())
sublist = [relist[x:x+332] for x in range(0, len(relist), 332)]  
data = [(1.4, 2500, 8, x)  for x in sublist]
data = [x  for x in sublist]
threads = list()
from threading import Thread
for i in range(12):
    process = Thread(target=find_something2, args=(1.4,2500,8,data[i],i,results))
    process.start()
    threads.append(process)
for process in threads:
    process.join()
```

But as I realised the time was almost the same for both parallel and serial execution. Would i have better results using thread pool? The problem as I said is that the function I am trying to run parallel must return a list. So in the above example I store each result from thread at a global list variable.

I also add the find_something function and worth_buy function that are running. I am using this for current_day>'2005-01-01' so don look at other references.

```
def find_something2(threl=2.0, my_limit=150, far=365, mystocks=None,index=None,results=None):
""" Find stocks that are worth buying"""
global current_date, total_money, min_date, current_name, dates_dict, mylist, min_date_sell, reduced_stocks
worthing = list()
if current_date < '2005-01-01':
    for stock in mylist:
        if dates_dict[stock][0] <= min_date:  # don't open all files
            frame = open_txt(stock)
            temp = frame.loc[current_date:end_date]
            if not temp.empty:
                mydate = temp.head(far).Low.idxmin()
                my_min = temp.head(far).Low.min()
                if total_money >= my_min > 0:  # find the min date at four months
                    ans, res, when_sell, total, income = worth_buy(stock, frame, mydate, 'Low',
                                                                   thres=threl,
                                                                   sell_limit=my_limit)
                    if ans:
                        if current_date > '2015-01-01':
                            if total >= 1000:
                                worthing.append([mydate, stock, res, when_sell, total, income])
                        elif current_date > '2000-01-01':
                            if income > 3 * 10 ** 6:
                                worthing.append([mydate, stock, res, when_sell, total, income])
                        elif current_date > '1985-01-01':
                            if income > 1.5 * 10 ** 6:
                                worthing.append([mydate, stock, res, when_sell, total, income])
                        else:
                            worthing.append([mydate, stock, res, when_sell, total, income])
else:
    for stock in mystocks:
        frame = reduced_stocks[stock]
        temp = frame.loc[current_date:end_date]
        if not temp.empty:
            mydate = temp.head(far).Low.idxmin()
            my_min = temp.head(far).Low.min()
            if total_money >= my_min > 0:  # find the min date at four months
                ans, res, when_sell, total, income = worth_buy(stock, frame, mydate, 'Low',
                                                               thres=threl, sell_limit=my_limit)
                if ans:
                    if income > 3 * 10 ** 6:
                        worthing.append([mydate, stock, res, when_sell, total, income])
if current_date > '1990-01-01':
    results[index] = sorted(worthing, key=itemgetter(0))
elif current_date > '1985-01-01':
    return sorted(worthing, key=itemgetter(0))
else:
    answer = sorted(worthing, key=itemgetter(5), reverse=True)
    return answer[::11]

def worth_buy(stock, frame, date, code, thres=2.0, sell_limit=0):
""" Checks if the stock is worth buying"""
global keep_time, end_date, total_money
over = find_limit(date, sell_limit)
checking = frame.loc[date:over]
if checking.empty:
    return False, 0, '', 0, 0  # anything at date limits
if stock not in purchased:
    when_sell = ((checking.High / frame.at[date, code]).idxmax())
else:
    possible_dates = purchased[stock][3].split(sep='/')
    other_sell = find_limit(possible_dates[-1], 1)
    checking2 = checking.loc[other_sell:]
    if checking2.empty:
        return False, 0, '', 0, 0  # anything at date limits
    when_sell = (checking2.High / frame.at[date, code]).idxmax()
buy_value = frame.at[date, code]
sell_value = frame.at[when_sell, code]
total = buy_total(frame, date, code, when_sell)
ans = sell_value / buy_value  # mporw na exw sunartisi
income = (sell_value - buy_value) * total
if when_sell <= end_date:
    return ans >= thres, ans, when_sell, total, income
else:
    return False, 0, '', 0, 0
```

Is there a chance time not going better because most time is spending at reading data instead of processing them? I think, but not sure that as I am just reading and not writing I would must have better result using multithreading.

Another important thing is that find_something function and the others does not update any global value, everything at this point is read-only. I have stored at memory all data frames which I access through their name that I have stored at a dictionary.

Thanks in advance

Edit this is how I store data frames in dictionary:

```
def initialize():
global current_date, file_names, current_name, dates_dict, mylist, sell_when, min_date_sell
worthing = 1
for stock in file_names:
    if getsize('C:/Users/tzagk/Downloads/Stocks/' + stock) > 0:
        frame = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/tzagk/Downloads/Stocks/' + stock, dtype=size_dict, usecols=use_cols, header=0,
                            index_col=0)
        dates_dict[stock] = [frame.index[0], frame]  # store start_time, data frame
        mylist.append(stock)
        if frame.index[0] <= min_date:  #
            check_date = frame.head(365).Low.idxmin()
            if frame.head(365).Low.min() <= 1:  # find the min date at four months
                ans, res, when_sell, total, income = worth_buy(stock, frame, check_date,
                                                               code='Low', thres=1.2,
                                                               sell_limit=3000)
                if ans:
                    if res > worthing:  # check best worth
                        worthing = res
                        current_date = check_date  # set start date
                        current_name = stock
                        min_date_sell = when_sell
```

Comment: Threads suffer from the global interpreter lock (GIL). So if Thread 1 is reading the data and performing some calculations thread #2 can't immediately do the exactly same. Thread #2 has to wait that #1 finishes a certain line in the code before in a can execute this line. Could you dump your dataframes in files (using pickle). That way you can use multiprocessing. Or use shared dictionaries instead of panda dataframes to store your data.

Comment: Can you please give me some more information about shared dictionaries? Dumping frames in files i think would not a good idea. I read sll of them in every loop and they are 1gb. I think the global problem is not happening in my code. Data frames i have are stock values. Every thread is accessing different stocks. I have one dict thst uses as key the stock name and i pass different keys at each thread

Comment: i added the code i store data frames

Comment: Could you read the stock in the threads instead of storing them in the dataframes before? So that you create the data directly in the threads. That way you wouldn't have to transfer the data between the threads. You would only have to give the stock name to the sub threads.